# Sybase codec for OSWAP ESAPI

Tags: java, sybase, codec, owasp, esapi

I use sybase database.

If I want to use OWASP ESAPI to prevent SQL Injection

Which codec I should use?

OracleCodec ?
MySQLCodec ?
DB2Codec ?
https://static.javadoc.io/org.owasp.esapi/esapi/2.0.1/org/owasp/esapi/codecs/package-summary.html

Thank you!

Comment: ESAPI 2.0.1 is massively out of date and contains security flaws.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost, do not use ESAPI to prevent SQL Injection.  The design intent of all of the SQL encoding codecs that exist, was to provide an emergency measure in incidents where a website got hacked, and you need something quick and dirty in place while you rewrite all your queries to use [Prepared Statements.](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc01776.1603/doc/html/san1357754834113.html)

[Here's an excerpt of documentation for the OracleCodec](https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy/blob/develop/src/main/java/org/owasp/esapi/codecs/OracleCodec.java):

```
/**
 * Implementation of the Codec interface for Oracle strings. This function will only protect you from SQLi in the case of user data
 * bring placed within an Oracle quoted string such as:
 * 
 * select * from table where user_name='  USERDATA    ';
```

Ignore the following words from the Sybase manual:

**Do not prepare statements that are used only once**

Use Prepared Statements or stored procedures for ***all*** database transactions.  In almost a decade of engineering, I've never actually seen a real life performance penalty for using Prepared Statements.  In most languages, performance improves.  This is certainly the case for Java.

Here's what a Prepared Statement looks like:

**[2019 EDIT]**
The below code could technically be an SQLi itself, back when I wrote this I meant to point out that the `dbName` parameter is safe to use in this way *only* when the server has absolute control over the value.**[/2019]**

```
String updateString =
    "update " + dbName + ".COFFEES " +
    "set SALES = ? where COF_NAME = ?";
updateSales = con.prepareStatement(updateString);
```

[Here are more.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

There is currently no Sybase codec provided by ESAPI, and there are currently no plans to develop one.

Source:  I am currently project co-lead for ESAPI.

Comment: I am maintaining some huge and old code. Which  use  string concatenate method by complex for and if statement to execute the sql. It's  vulnerable for sql injection.  I don't want to rewrite them by prepared statement. I think the OSWAP ESAPI is the easiest way to protect the sql injection. Just wrap variables by a escape function.  And don't break the original logic. Therefore it may minimum the side effect. Unfortunately there are no sybase codec support. So if I use the oracle or mysql or db2 codec. What will happen? Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: And it will continue to be vulnerable to SQL injection even after ESAPI, because they are designed for emergency use only, typically the ONLY thing we escape in those codecs are single quotes, and that only blocks ONE kind of SQLi.  We leave them broken like that on purpose, because the correct solution are ‘Prepared Statements.’  You have been warned.

Comment: Your only other option is to write the BNF grammar for Sybase’s syntax and use a tool like yacc or Javacc to roll your own parser.  That option requires a lot more testing which is why the recommendation from OWASP is Prepared Statements.  All that testing is done for you.

Comment: And most languages—especially SQL—contain parsing corner cases that are vendor specific.  A BNF might break legal syntax.

Comment: If you just wanted that Bare bone of protection, you COULD do what you suggest, but I would NEVER recommend that to any application team I support.  If money is the problem, explain it to the stake holders, and have them sign off on the risks in writing.  You don’t want to get fired if the app gets hacked.

Comment: If the problem is, you don’t want to be bothered with the work, ask yourself if you’d rather write prepared statements or look for a new job because the application got hacked?

Comment: OK, Thank you very much !

Comment: Here is OWASP's complete guide to preventing SQLi:  https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: If you really can't rewrite the queries into Stored Procedures, analyze all of the inputs and whitelist legal characters only.  This isn't as safe, but its better than escaping data.

Comment: Especially look into the section on hex-encoding.

Comment: Thank you! You are so kind!

Comment: When you can't use prepared statements for values like `dbName` in your example above, would that be a good place for the ESAPI encodeForSQL?  Agreed that a whitelist is better but sometimes the valid values are not known.

Comment: @MattH You pointed out indirectly that I sort of messed up that example. The problem is the proprietary nature of RDBMS and that the BNF Grammars aren't typically published, there's no way to get better protection than from a prepared statement.  So I can't recommend our lib as more than a stopgap.  If however, you had access to the BNF you could use tools like javacc, flex, or bison to construct a parser.